# Compare mysql datetime value with current date and hour only

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a datetime column named 'follow_up_on', I'm trying to match its values with current date and hour.

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H');
$results = $db->query("
Select *
     , DATE_FORMAT(follow_up_on, '%Y %m %d %H') 
  from leads 
 where follow_up_on = '$currentDate'
");
```

This is what I have tried but no success

Comment: $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H');
$results = $db->query("Select *,DATE_FORMAT(follow_up_on, '%Y-%m-%d %H') from leads where DATE_FORMAT(follow_up_on, '%Y-%m-%d %H') = '$currentDate'");

Comment: what datatype you are using for follow_uo_on

Comment: Yes that worked @Abdul Jabbar

Answer (score 1):

This made it work

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H'); 

    $results = $db->query("Select *,DATE_FORMAT(follow_up_on, '%Y-%m-%d %H') from leads where DATE_FORMAT(follow_up_on, '%Y-%m-%d %H') = '$currentDate'");
```

Comment: This query will not use index if defined for `follow_up_on` column